# Storing an array (doubles) in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, insert, phpmyadmin

I'm very new to MySQL, although I've used SQL databases in other contexts before. I have a test site set up which has an online cPanel with access to phpMyAdmin. I'm attempting to setup a MySQL database, and so far it's working fine (I can connect to the Database *and* the table).

The only problem I'm having is with inserting data. I'd like to insert an entire array (specifically, the array will be a `double[]`) into one column. After looking at the column types available in phpMyAdmin, it doesn't seem to support inserting arrays other than Binary arrays.

I've found many solutions for inserting arrays programatically including [this](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/1500.htm) thread, but for this site we will be inserting data via the online cPanel. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The language is irrelevant to the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access to that data, and want to be able to use the power of SQL to search in your double[], you should do it this way:

First, you should spend some time researching relational databases. They allow you to create linked data.

An important part of every relational database is using good keys. A key is a unique identifier for a row that allows you to access the data on that row in an efficient manner.

Another important part of relational databases are indexes. Indexes are not required to be unique. But are useful if you are trying to search on them (SQL has made an "index" of the table based on a column or group of columns)

If you wanted to create a table that would have a double[] array, you might instead create a 2nd table that relates to the first table by the first tables primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE base (
    base_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name    VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY(base_id)
);

CREATE TABLE darray (
    base_id INT,
    data    DOUBLE,
    INDEX(base_id)
);
```

To get the information back out that you want, you can select using a `JOIN` statement. If you wanted to get all the information where the base_id was 3, you would write it like so:

```
SELECT * FROM base
    JOIN darray ON darray.base_id = base.base_id
WHERE base.base_id = 3;
```

The advanced form of writing this with aliasing

```
SELECT * FROM base b
    JOIN darray d ON d.base_id = b.base_id
WHERE b.base_id = 3;
```

---

If you don't want to have access to the data, but are just recalling it, you should do it this way: (Although this is debatable, I still recommend the above way, if you are willing to learn more sql)

I assume you will be using PHP, we will be serializing the data (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Note we will don't have the darray table, but instead add a

```
data    BLOB
```

to the base table.

Inserting with PHP serialized data

```
<?php
$serializedData = serialize($darray);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO base (name, data) VALUES('a name', '$serializedData ')");
```

Getting the serialized data

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM base WHERE base_id=3");
if($result && mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0) {
    $serializedData = mysql_result($result, 0, 'data');
    $darray = unserialize($serializedData);
}
```

Comment: Although this answer didn't really address the question, this is what I will eventually end up doing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can import data for tables with a `.sql` file (basically just a file full of insertion queries) but phpMyAdmin doesn't support inserting data from arbitrary data types. If you want to insert a `double[]` array as multiple rows in a table, you'll need to take an approach similar to the one in the thread you linked.

(Note that you can always write such a program for the explicit purpose of generating a `.sql` file which you then use for deployment.)

Comment: I don't think he wants to "import" but rather "insert"

Comment: "I'm attempting to setup a MySQL database." The difference is academic at this point, though.

Comment: fair enough, I just read "setting up" as making a schema to store his data.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific.. I was looking for a way to insert data through cPanel. Although if that can't be done I may end up having to import the data from a local file.

Comment: You can insert data with cPanel, but you probably can't make it fully automated for a `double[]` array (unless you write a program to export the array as a list of doubles, in which case you might as well just make it write the query.) How were you thinking of getting that `double[]` into cPanel? What kind of format is it currently in, if not stored in memory? @Snailer

Comment: I was just planning on having one of our admins login to cPanel and manually insert rows of data. ie- they click "Insert" and under column "someDoubleArray" they'd just copy/paste an array in some kind of format (perhaps "{ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 }")

Comment: In that case, just run an `INSERT` query on that table with the data. The syntax for actually listing the numbers will be nearly identical.